# Running a python code as a windows service using a bat file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, service

I have a python code which i want to run it as a windows service. to archive this, what i did i have created two bat files.

first bat file contains following commands:

```
@echo off
call "venv\Scripts\activate.bat"
python -m atm.solution.channel
pause
```

now using my second bat file, i am trying to run my first bat file as a windows services.

second bat file contains following commands:

```
@echo off

set ServiceName=AtmSystemABCaaaaaaa
set BatchFilePath=G:\kaveesha\20230418\2\ATMproject\4.bat

echo Creating service...
sc create %ServiceName% binPath= "%BatchFilePath%" start= auto
echo Service created.

echo Configuring service...
sc config %ServiceName% start= auto
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\%ServiceName%\TimeOut" /v "WaitToKillServiceTimeout" /t REG_DWORD /d 12000000 /f
echo Service timeout value set.

echo Setting service failure actions...
sc.exe failure %ServiceName% actions= restart/5000/restart/5000/restart/5000
echo Service failure actions set.

echo Starting service...
sc start %ServiceName%
echo Service started.

pause
```

now when i ran the first bat file to check whether it's working or not. so first bat file running without any issue. but when i ran my second bat file, it creates the service. but it didn't start the service. it gives following error:

[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Does this help you? https://superuser.com/a/1737281